# Analyze peculiar avcC atom structure

Tags: mp4, h.264

I need some help to understand the `avcC` atom structure of a particular mp4 sample I am trying to analyze.

Hex dump:

> 00 00 00 38 61 76 63 43 01 64 00 1F FF E1 00 1C 67 64 00 1F AC D9 80
> 50 05 BB 01 6A 02 02 02 80 00 00 03 00 80 00 00 1E 07 8C 18 CD 01 00
> 05 68 E9 7B 2C 8B FD F8 F8 00 00 00 00 13 63 6F 6C 72

This is what I understand from the above:

`00 00 00 38` Size of avcC atom

`61 76 63 43` avcC signature

`01` configurationVersion

`64` AVCProfileIndication

`00` profile_compatibility

`1F` AVCLevelIndication

`FF` 111111b + lengthSizeMinusOne

`E1` 111b + numOfSequenceParameterSets (in this case, 1 SPS)

`00 1C` SPS length (in this case, 28 bytes)

`67 64 00 1F AC D9 80 50 05 BB 01 6A 02 02 02 80 00 00 03 00 80 00 00 1E 07 8C 18 CD` SPS data (28 bytes as per above)

`01` numOfPictureParameterSets (in this case, 1 PPS)

`00 05` PPS length

This is where the problem begins. Based on the PPS length given by the previous bytes, the next 5 bytes should be the PPS data: `68 E9 7B 2C 8B`

However according to the avcC header, the total length of the atom is 56 bytes (`0x38`), which means that the following 4 bytes should be included: `FD F8 F8 00`

But the problem is that the PPS length is given as 5 bytes (`0x05`). So what exactly are these final 4 bytes?

Then follows the header of the `colr` atom:

`00 00 00 13` size of colr atom

`63 6F 6C 72` colr signature

Which I have checked and is indeed 19 bytes in length (`0x13`).

The problem is with the avcC atom and with that particular mp4 sample I am analyzing (I've checked other samples too and they didn't have this peculiarity).

You can find the sample [here](https://file-examples-com.github.io/uploads/2017/04/file_example_MP4_1280_10MG.mp4).

**EDIT**

`mp4info` tool from the bento4 suite reports the following as the avcC atom's size: `8+48`

And `mp4dump` reports:

```
AVC SPS: [6764001facd9805005bb016a02020280000003008000001e078c18cd]

AVC PPS: [68e97b2c8b]
```

So it correctly reports the total size of the atom as 56 bytes (0x38) based on what is found in the avcC header, but the SPS/PPS data are analyzed the same way as above. I still don't understand what the final 4 bytes are or where do they belong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dind't get any answer but fortunately a bit more careful reading of `ISO 14496-15` solved this issue:

```
if( profile_idc == 100 || profile_idc == 110 ||
    profile_idc == 122 || profile_idc == 144 )
{
   bit(6) reserved = ‘111111’b;
   unsigned int(2) chroma_format;
   bit(5) reserved = ‘11111’b;
   unsigned int(3) bit_depth_luma_minus8;
   bit(5) reserved = ‘11111’b;
   unsigned int(3) bit_depth_chroma_minus8;
   unsigned int(8) numOfSequenceParameterSetExt;
   for (i=0; i< numOfSequenceParameterSetExt; i++) {
      unsigned int(16) sequenceParameterSetExtLength;
      bit(8*sequenceParameterSetExtLength) sequenceParameterSetExtNALUnit;
   }
}
```

Apparently a sequence of 4+ bytes may exist at the end of an avcC atom depending on the profile used. In my sample above the profile is 100 (`0x64`), hence it meets the criteria. So the last 4 bytes are:

`FD` = bits `111111` are reserved, remaining `01` means chroma subsampling 4:2:0

`F8` = bits `11111` are reserved, remaining `000` means luma bit depth is 8

`F8` = bits `11111` are reserved, remaining `000` means chroma bit depth is 8

`00` = zero SPS extensions

Comment: You rock! Thanks for figuring it out. FWIW, this information is also buried in the SPS atom and can be pulled out by an exp-Golomb reader. I suppose they stuck it in the codec-private 'avcC' atom to make it easier for byte-aligned software to access.

Comment: @O. Jones Apparently some tools read the SPS data directly instead of parsing the easier avcC surrounding format to get information. Ex. MediaInfo reads the 2nd byte of the SPS data to populate its `Format_Profile` parameter instead of the `AVCProfileIndication` byte of the avcC atom (I verified this with a hex editor). I suspect the same happens with MI's `ChromaSubsampling` field but I can't verify it yet because I haven't figured out how to do exp-Golomb parsing... altering the `FD` of the last 4 bytes above changes nothing.

Comment: I figured out the parsing of SPS / PPS / avcC.   https://github.com/OllieJones/h264-interp-utils I'll be adding those extra bytes soon per your explanation.

Comment: Thanks for that, I'll look into it